# OpenGL on Android using C++ only

Tags: c++, android, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android application for Android 2.1.

I'm trying to code OpenGL's stuff with C++ only.

Do you know a tutorial or an article showing an example about how to do that?

**UPDATE**:

Sorry, I've forget to say that I will use a Java home application to launch main activity.

I'm trying to say if I have to code on Java glSurfaceView or this statement must be on C++ code.

Ok, better explained: If I have a complete openGl on C++, may I have to modify C++ code?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that at present you can't make a C++ only application that can be launched from a normal home application.  You have to have java initialization code regardless if you figure out how to implement all the functionality natively.  This is and the missing native API's are IMHO one of the biggest shortfalls of the platform - it's really a shame you can't fully leverage the underlying embedded linux platform by normal means.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: thanks. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Android NDK there is a san-angeles demo under the samples directory which shows off using OpenGL ES 1.x in C code and a Java wrapper. As for changes to already existing C++ code be aware that there is no official STL implementation for the NDK r4 (although I believe there are some ports available) [edit: as of NDK r5 there is a STLport based implementation of STL]. And I'm guessing that you'll need to mimic what the demo does for the GLSurfaceView since outside events (touch, keyboard, etc.) along with the Android activity lifecycle must be to be handled by the Java side. If you are looking for a OpenGL ES 2.0 example, there is a basic one in the samples directory of the Android NDK as well.

Comment: I'm also following this tutorial http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/

Answer (score 2):

According to http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk you can't do it purely in C++.  As you suggest in your update, you'll need to do the application with the standard (Java) SDK, but can create C++ libraries and call into them.  With respect to OpenGL, the article suggests that you have full access to OpenGL ES, either 1.1 or 2.0.  ES is not the same as the full OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Try Arm Developer Center [link](https://arm-software.github.io/opengl-es-sdk-for-android/tutorials.html). 
It has native tutorials on basics of an OpenGL ES application.