# Basic OpenGLES tutorials in C++ for android?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am trying to find some very basic tutorials like how to draw a line, how to draw a triangle, how to draw a rectangle etc using OpenGLES in android. All the tutorials I found are in Java but I am looking for C++ based samples. I'll be very thankful if someone can point me to such tutorials.

**Update**

I am creating activity and renderer in Java but I want to implement/redirect methods like OnDrawFrame, OnSurfaceChanged and OnSurfaceCreated in/to C++.

Comment: I learnt by buying the "OpenGL Superbible" and spending a weekend reading the first few chapters very carefully. I thoroughly recommend the book approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to first learn OpenGL (2.0+) on the desktop and then move to OpenGL|ES. As a beginner you are bound to make mistakes and it will be easier to find, fix and learn from them as well the theory and requirements of 3D rendering. When you have a firm grasp you could make the jump instantly into OGL|ES with just the [reference pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) at hand.

For a crash course though, this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Android-Games-Books-Professionals/dp/1430226471) and [that](http://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-ES-2-0-Programming-Guide/dp/0321502795/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318288868&sr=1-1) have proven quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question is asked earlier..
[OpenGL on Android using C++ only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071495/opengl-on-android-using-c-only)
may be its useful for you..
But the correct approach is first learn opengl because opengles is like a subset of opengl.
here a link for a good book [http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-SuperBible-Comprehensive-Tutorial-Reference/dp/0321712617/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318312610&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712617)